# jQuery validate form on normal button (not submit)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, button

Hi I have a form that comes in 2 parts and on the click  of a button, the part of the form showing slides up to hidden and the next (previously hidden) slides down to come into view.

However, I want the part of the form filled in to be validated before it slides up and I can't find a way of doing this without using an input type="submit"when I want to be using an input type="button" so that the page doesn't reload.

Any way of using jQuery to validate form on click of a normal button rather than a submit button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#btn").click(function() { $("#form").validate(); });`

Comment: How simple?! Good grief I was looking for ages for that! Thank you so much